# hierarchy query which gives output in multiple rows , want output in one row

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, hierarchical-data

i have one hierarchical table , i fetch hierarchical data  but its coming in rows as shown below :
table structure :

```
id      parent_type parent_id    
    71123   FSE         67114       
    67114   DST         67111          
    67111   null            0
```

output of hierarchy :

```
id      parent_type parent_id   level   SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(parent_type, '->') 
71123   FSE         67114       1      ->FSE
67114   DST         67111       2      ->FSE->DST
67111   null            0       3      ->FSE->DST->

I WANT RESULT OF ABOVE OUTPUT AS SHOWN BELOW:
id   parent_type parent_id   id   parent_type parent_id  id    parent_type parent_id   
71123   FSE      67114       67114 DST        67111      67111 NULL  0
```

Comment: Its not clear what do u want actually?

Comment: kya apko ye html me show karna hai?

Comment: You need to [`pivot`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#CHDFAFIE), but do you know how many levels you might have to deal with? Maybe you have a reporting or application layer that can do that for display instead.

Comment: no , through sql i need to do this and  max levels can be  5

Answer (score 0):

Might look too complicated but its actually easy.

```
WITH dat
     AS (SELECT 71123 AS id,
                'FSE' AS parent_type,
                67114 AS parent_id
         FROM   DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 67114 AS id,
                'DST' AS parent_type,
                67111 AS parent_id
         FROM   DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 67111 AS id,
                NULL AS parent_type,
                0 AS parent_id
         FROM   DUAL)
SELECT MAX (id_level_1) AS id_level_1,
       MAX (parent_type_level_1) AS parent_type_level_1,
       MAX (parent_id_level_1) AS parent_id_level_1,
       MAX (id_level_2) AS id_level_2,
       MAX (parent_type_level_2) AS parent_type_level_2,
       MAX (parent_id_level_2) AS parent_id_level_2,
       MAX (id_level_3) AS id_level_3,
       MAX (parent_type_level_3) AS parent_type_level_3,
       MAX (parent_id_level_3) AS parent_id_level_3,
       MAX (id_level_4) AS id_level_4,
       MAX (parent_type_level_4) AS parent_type_level_4,
       MAX (parent_id_level_4) AS parent_id_level_4,
       MAX (id_level_5) AS id_level_5,
       MAX (parent_type_level_5) AS parent_type_level_5,
       MAX (parent_id_level_5) AS parent_id_level_5
FROM   (SELECT CASE WHEN l = 1 THEN id ELSE NULL END AS id_level_1,
               CASE WHEN l = 1 THEN parent_type ELSE NULL END AS parent_type_level_1,
               CASE WHEN l = 1 THEN parent_id ELSE NULL END AS parent_id_level_1,
               CASE WHEN l = 2 THEN id ELSE NULL END AS id_level_2,
               CASE WHEN l = 2 THEN parent_type ELSE NULL END AS parent_type_level_2,
               CASE WHEN l = 2 THEN parent_id ELSE NULL END AS parent_id_level_2,
               CASE WHEN l = 3 THEN id ELSE NULL END AS id_level_3,
               CASE WHEN l = 3 THEN parent_type ELSE NULL END AS parent_type_level_3,
               CASE WHEN l = 3 THEN parent_id ELSE NULL END AS parent_id_level_3,
               CASE WHEN l = 4 THEN id ELSE NULL END AS id_level_4,
               CASE WHEN l = 4 THEN parent_type ELSE NULL END AS parent_type_level_4,
               CASE WHEN l = 4 THEN parent_id ELSE NULL END AS parent_id_level_4,
               CASE WHEN l = 5 THEN id ELSE NULL END AS id_level_5,
               CASE WHEN l = 5 THEN parent_type ELSE NULL END AS parent_type_level_5,
               CASE WHEN l = 5 THEN parent_id ELSE NULL END AS parent_id_level_5
        FROM   (SELECT id,
                       parent_type,
                       parent_id,
                       LEVEL AS l
                FROM   dat
                START WITH id = 71123
                CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_id = id));
```

Here is the result 
ID_LEVEL_1|PARENT_TYPE_LEVEL_1|PARENT_ID_LEVEL_1|ID_LEVEL_2|PARENT_TYPE_LEVEL_2|PARENT_ID_LEVEL_2|ID_LEVEL_3|PARENT_TYPE_LEVEL_3|PARENT_ID_LEVEL_3|ID_LEVEL_4|PARENT_TYPE_LEVEL_4|PARENT_ID_LEVEL_4|ID_LEVEL_5|PARENT_TYPE_LEVEL_5|PARENT_ID_LEVEL_5
     71123|                FSE|            67114|     67114|                DST|            67111|     67111|                   |                0|          |                   |                 |          |                   |

But do understand that it will only work for 5 levels like you stated in your question.